# Where are tag messages in Sourcetree

Tags: git, version-control, git-gui, gitk, atlassian-sourcetree

Where can I access the corresponding message of git tags in Sourcetree.  The context menu of a tag seems not to offer such an option.

Answer (score 12):

This is dependent on whether it's Mac or Windows, and whether you're using Git or Mercurial. Since you're using Git that information is available - you can just context-click on a tag from the sidebar and click 'Details' which will show you the metadata related to that tag.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to view this without going to the Tab list? Ie. By right-clicking on a tag inside the source tree?

Answer (score 2):

```
git show tag-name
```

will show you the message and the commit the tag is pointing to including it's message as well.

I don't know of a way to see it via `gitk`.

Comment: I know, but how do I access this message in Sourcetree, the git gui

Comment: There is no option for that unfortunately. File a feature request?

Comment: In gitk you can just click the tag and it will show the message.